# Defining file name at runtime - Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement to build a spring-batch application to read one file per day from a pre-defined folder. The file name has a prefix pattern but it ends up with the current date. For example, day one this file would be named foo_20210323, and at day two another file would be placed in the same folder with the name foo_20210324. Every day my Spring-batch application is considering the file name created at compile time. **How to change the application in order to define the file name at runtime**?

- Project is all based on Java Configuration.
- org.springframework.scheduling.quartz as the internal scheduler.
- File name being defined in a specific class.
- File name passed as parameter for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, depending on how you pass the current date to your job (as a job parameter, with a system property, etc).

If you pass the date as a job parameter, you can use a step-scoped item reader and inject the value at runtime from the job parameters. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<String> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['date']}") String date) {
   return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<>()
          .resource(new FileSystemResource("/data/in/foo_" + date))
          // set other properties
          .build();
}
```

You can find more details in the [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section of the reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, Mahmoud. I followed your tips: * set the method as step scope * set the jobParameter But as I am new to Spring universe, I don't know how to call the method with a jobParameters in the step flow configuration. Here is my step: return stepBuilderFactory.get("BatchCoarrec_step2") .<Coarrec, List<CoarrecEvento>> chunk(500) .reader(itemReader()) .processor(eventoProcessor()) .writer(eventoWriter()) .build(); Could you help me again? – Luis Franco 4 mins ago    Edit   Delete

Comment: You are welcome. You can pass `null` (or any other value) to the reader method like: `.reader(itemReader(null))`. The value you pass at configuration time does not matter since it will be overridden at runtime anyway with the late-binding technique. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, Mahmoud. Sorry for the late reply. I followed your instructions and now my application is working fine with late biding of step attributes. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: before you ask me to accept the awnser I have tried to accept. But I got this message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: ok no problem, since you don't have enough reputation to accept the answer, you can upvote it. Otherwise, no worries, the most important part is that your issue is solved now :-) Glad to be of help.

Comment: Mahmoud, sorry for my small knowledge over stackoverflow platform. I think I was trying to upvote instead of accepting the answer. It seems that now the answer is accepted. Thanks one more time for your attention. Your help was crucial to get the things done.